# Excel VBA Macro: Formatting Duplicates and Uniques

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a spread sheet where each row consists of information about a member of a group. In  each cell of column `B` there is an integer that represents each person (i.e., think of an member ID). All members have a unique ID.

I would like to use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates in red.

The problem is that because of copy-pasting to the spreadsheet instead of typing, the conditional formatting in the affected cell is erased. This means that the duplicate detection is gone. Also, long integers turn into scientific notation which is inconvenient.

I tried a VBA procedure to fix this issue. I defined the function `EnforceFormat`, which should force formatting in all cells of columns B, except `B1`, every time a change is made to the spreadsheet. The editor did not return any errors so I thought it would be fine. But once I got back to the spreadsheet, I noticed that the macro wasn't doing anything.

What is wrong with my code? Also which attributes should I add to disable scientific notation and dictate the exact font?

```
Sub EnforceFormat()
    'Define Range for Conditional Formatting
    Dim EnforcedRange As Range
    
    'Set Range for Conditional Formatting
    Set EnforcedRange = Range("B2:B1048576")
    
    'Define Rule for Duplicates
    Dim Uniques1 As UniqueValues
    
    'Set Rule and Style for Duplicates
    Set Uniques1 = EnforcedRange.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Uniques1.DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    Uniques1.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Uniques1.Font.Bold = True
    Uniques1.Font.Size = 17
    
    'Define Rule for Uniques
    Dim Uniques2 As UniqueValues
    
    'Set Rule and Style for Uniques
    Set Uniques2 = EnforcedRange.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    Uniques2.DupeUnique = xlUnique
    Uniques2.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Uniques2.Font.Bold = False
    Uniques2.Font.Size = 15
End Sub
```

Comment: Generally, it would be useful to see the structure of your input data, otherwise it is difficult to judge. At the same time, I do not quiet see why a VBA procedure is required for this. Well, of course, if you simply copy and paste you overwrite also the conditional formatting. However, if you use as paste option "Values (V)", then both the conditional formatting and the formatting of the cells is kept accordingly. This can be achieved by right-click and paste as values or with CTRL + ALT + V, which then let you select the paste option.